# Use ParametricNDSolve to get derivative at roots

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, parametric-functions

$ \ddot{s} = \frac{\mathrm{Thrust}(t)}{m} - g $

$ \dot{s}(0) = v_0 $

$ s(0) = s_0$

Where Thrust(t) is a piecewise interpolation function. 
I want to obtain a function which gives me the maximum speed when $s(t) = 0$ given $v_0$ and $s_0$. The maximum speed is chosen from all the speeds when s(t) = 0 as there may be multiple t when this condition is satisfied. (clarification added due to comment)

```
thrustCurve = Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/shyR8vJp", "Table"];
ifun = Interpolation[thrustCurve, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
Thrust[t_] = Piecewise[{{ifun[t], 0 < t < 3.45}}];
m = 1.0565
g = 9.80655
```

I got it working with one parameter like this, however this only samples the function at specific points.

```
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{s''[x] == Thrust[x]/m - g, s'[0] == vo, s[0] == so,
                         WhenEvent[s[x] == 0, If[x > 3.45, "StopIntegration",
                                   s'[x] -> 0]]}, {s, s'}, {x, 0, ∞}, {vo, so}];
h = s /. % ;
v = s' /. sol;   
velocities = Max[Abs[#' /@ (t /. Table[FindRoot[#[t], {t, t0, 0, #["Domain"][[1, 2]]}], {t0, 0, #["Domain"][[1, 2]], 1}])]] & /@ Table[h[va, 20], {va, -15, 5, 1}]
```

I'm not sure how to do it with two parameters, ideally I could do something like the following, so the function is continuous.

```
ParametricNDSolve[{s''[x] == Thrust[x]/m - g, s'[0] == vo, s[0] == so,
                   WhenEvent[s[x] == 0, yu -> t; If[x > 3.45, "StopIntegration",
                   s'[x] -> 0]]}, s'[yu], {x, 0, ∞}, {vo , so}];
```

If its helpful, I want this function in order to minimise it in real time (on an Arduino) w.r.t to another variable (which can be used to generate a range of $v_0$ and $s_0$)

UPDATE:
I have managed to get it working with two parameters by sampling at specific points with the same functions as in the one parameter example. However, I still want to be able to get a continuous function and the current method is slow. Upon further testing, it crashes for certain ranges.

```
sstart = 10;
send = 100;
ds = 1;
vstart = -50;
vend = 0;
dv = 1;
velocities = ArrayReshape[Max[Abs[#' /@ (t /. Table[FindRoot[#[t], 
   {t, t0, 0, #["Domain"][[1, 2]]}], {t0, 0, #["Domain"][[1, 2]], #["Domain"][[1, 2]]}])]] 
         & /@ Flatten[Table[h[va, sa], {va, vstart, vend, dv}, {sa, sstart, send, 
              ds}]], {Abs[vstart - vend]/ dv + 1, Abs[sstart - send]/ ds + 1}];
```

Comment: Could you not convert your Excel file to a CSV file and post the contents of that to [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com)?

Comment: The data is available here: https://nar.org/SandT/pdf/Estes/F15.pdf on the last page. I haven't had any trouble with it so I didn't think it was necessary to include it.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/shyR8vJp for easier copy pasting.

Comment: A good reason for putting it in Pastebin is that it makes importing stuff into *Mathematica* easier; look at how I changed the definition of `thrustCurve` for reference.

Comment: I'm not quite clear what you're looking for.  Your working solution (in the second code block) has two parameters `vo` and `so`, not one.  What are you trying to add to the second block?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "the maximum speed when $s(t) = 0$ given $v_0$ and $s_0$"?  What are you maximizing the speed with respect to?

Comment: Sorry the code must have gotten deleted by accident. As there will be multiple times at which $s(t) = 0$, the maximum speed out of all of these times must be chosen. Hopefully the code makes it clear what I mean

Comment: @NeonNuke What are restrictions on `so,v0,x`?

Comment: They are all real and $so >= 0, x >= 0$. If need be $so$ and $vo$ can be limited in magnitude to below 1000 and 100 respectively, however it would be preferable if there was no such limitation.